# Selecting distinct values where input is in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table:

```
+----+------+--------------+
| id | r_usr_id | s_usr_id |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | 1        |  2       |
| 2  | 2        |  1       |
| 2  | 3        |  1       |
| 2  | 3        |  2       |
| 2  | 3        |  1       |
| 2  | 3        |  2       |
+----+------+--------------+
```

I want to pull all unique `id` values where an input id is in `r` or `s`.

For example, if I pass user 1, my desired result is:

```
+-----+
| ids |
+-----+
| 2   |
| 3   |
+-----+
```

If I used user 2, the result would be:

```
+-----+
| ids |
+-----+
| 1   |
| 3   |
+-----+
```

Comment: I'm confused, `id` 3 is no where in your sample data.

Comment: `r or s and r or s` huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do here is use a `DISTINCT` select statement and the `IN` operator to search for your id in one of the columns, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM myTable
WHERE @myInput IN (rColumn, sColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example data I assume you want to retrieve all `r_usr_id` where `s_usr_id` matches and vice versa?

```
SELECT r_usr_id FROM theTable WHERE s_usr_id = 1
UNION
SELECT s_usr_id FROM theTable WHERE r_usr_id = 1
```